# Regexp―match ' but not ''

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regexp that matches a quote, but not a two quotes in a row, so:

```
'    --> match,
''   --> no match and
'''  --> match the last '
```

I tried:

```
(?<!')'
```

but it does not work…

Thanks in ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
(?<!')(?:'')*(')(?!')
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL2yT6)

Comment: the match should not be bound to the beginning of the line… I will update my question

Comment: @philipp How about this regex? I used negative lookarounds instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match last quote (single or double):

```
"((['\"]){2})*\\2"
```

**Code:**

```
String repl = "'''".replaceAll("((['\"]){2})*\\2", "$1:"); //=> '':
```